# Angular 7.1.4 HTML Avoid copy-pasting to restructure

Tags: html, angular, dom

So I have my html that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #1</div>
    <div>Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #2</div>
    <div>Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #3</div>
    <div>Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #4</div>
</div>
```

And currently I am working on the CSS and layout, but this means that I am constantly restructuring the DOM:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #1</div>
        Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #2
        <div>Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #3</div>
        Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #4
    </div>
</div>
```

Or something like that.

I'v looked at `ng-template` but that only seems to work with `ngIf` and `ngSwitch`.

What I really want is something like this, where I don't have to re-copy all the content every time there is a layout change.
BTW, assume I can't create a new component and move it into that new component.

```
<div>
    <div copyFrom="#1"></div>
    <div>
        <div copyFrom="#2"></div>
        <div copyFrom="#3"></div>
    </div>
    <div copyFrom="#4"></div>
</div>
<div no-display name="#1">Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #1</div>
<div no-display name="#2">Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #2</div>
<div no-display name="#3">Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #3</div>
<div no-display name="#4">Lots of stuff that only appears in this component #4</div>
```

Is there a way to do this so that I don't have to copy-paste the content, and I can just copy-paste a REFERENCE to the content?

I'm using Angular 7.1.4.

Just because, because I have no idea what you may need to help me, here is the result of `ng --version`:

```
Angular CLI: 7.1.4
Node: 11.6.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.1.4
... cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.11.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.11.4
@angular-devkit/core              7.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.1.4
@angular/animations               7.2.0
@angular/cdk                      7.2.1
@angular/fire                     5.0.2
@angular/flex-layout              7.0.0-beta.23
@angular/material                 7.2.1
@ngtools/webpack                  7.1.4
@schematics/angular               7.1.4
@schematics/update                0.11.4
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.23.1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

```
<div>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template1"></ng-container>
    <div>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template2"></ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template3"></ng-container>
    </div>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template4"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #template1> ... </ng-template>
<ng-template #template2> ... </ng-template>
<ng-template #template3> ... </ng-template>
<ng-template #template4> ... </ng-template>
```